# MySQL Select From Prior Week, not just 7 days

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to get a query that selects the week prior (Sun-Sat). I've fought with this query and the closest I can get is the last 7 days, using the following:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM dates 
 WHERE date BETWEEN CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURDATE();
```

I'm really unsure how to proceed from here. It seems as if I need to create some kind of relation between `CURDATE()` and the Saturday before maybe?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are after the Week of the year.

Look at the Week Function:  WEEK(date[,mode])
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

The mode describes how you define the week (which is the start of the week)
WEEK(date,3) is for a week that starts Monday.

```
SELECT * 
 FROM dates 
 WHERE 
-- Last Week
WEEK(date,3)  = WEEK(CURDATE(),3)-1 

AND YEAR(date)= YEAR(CURDATE())  ;
```

Don't forget the year. Week is just a number between 1 and 52. So the Year is important!
The code above is not correct. **it will fail on the last week of the year!**

Comment: Hmm - thank you a lot for this - however it is producing an empty result...no rows are outputting.

Comment: This may help see how the query is misleading :
SELECT *, WEEK(date,3) , WEEK(CURDATE(),3)-1   FROM dates  Order by YEAR(date) DESC

Comment: Brian, thanks for this. This is producing results from every week that begins with "3", e.g. 30, 31, 32...